# How to use widgets from django snippet?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-widget

I want to use this widget in my code

https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/10522/

My question is where to paste this code? and how to use it in my forms?

My code requires me to select only month and date from the user using a drop-down menu. The date is set to '1' by default. I found this widget very helpful but I am unable to figure out how to use it in my code

Comment: Add more details. Show your code, structure or context, ask for something specific instead of asking a very wide question.

Comment: What's not clear in the doc ? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/widgets/

Comment: Also note that this snippet might not work with Django >= 1.11

Comment: Where should I use the code provided in the link? Like in which file should I paste it? @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: Wherever it makes sense for your project - there's no particular restriction here. If it's only used in a single form just put it in the same module as the form.

Answer (score 0):

Paste all of the code that creates the widgets in a file called "widgets.py". Then, to use it in your form, import widgets.py and you can add it to your form like so:

```
FROM .WIDGETS IMPORT widget_name

reserve_start = forms.DateTimeField(
        validators=[validate_reserveperiod],
        widget=widget_name()
    )
```

Django documentation is generally helpful and can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/widgets/#customizing-widget-instances):